# How to react-calendar formatMonth prop use for abbreviating the name of Month into 'MMM' format in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-calendar

I couldn't format the month name to 'MMM' format in react-calendar, can someone give the working example of renaming the react-calendar month name into 'MMM' format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFCk4.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your use case but did you try maybe to use date-fns library?
link to [documenatation](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started)

i am using format function and it works pretty damn good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).